# Error running '__rvm_make -j 1' during rvm Ruby installation | openssl error

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

**You are probably searching for *Error running '__rvm_make -j 1'***
That only says, that something went wrong while compiling ruby. This question is only relevant to you if **`openssl`** and/or **`ossl_ssl`** is part of your error message.
But maybe your problem is a *similar* one and you can solve your problem with some customizations.

---

**Background**
Today I wanted to delete all gems of a project but forgot to specify a path for bundler beforehand so all gems where installed in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/`.

As it's the only ruby 2.2.4 project I though `rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/*` would be perfectly fine. It wasn't. Bundler was gone and `gem install bundler` didn't worked anymore as well.

I removed the hole ruby installation with `rvm remove ruby-2.2.4` ant tried to reinstall it. This is the console output with the error I got:

**Console output**

```
> rvm install ruby-2.2.4
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/fkammer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.4 - #downloading ruby-2.2.4, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.7M  100 12.7M    0     0   655k      0  0:00:19  0:00:19 --:--:--  234k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.2.4 - #extracting ruby-2.2.4 to /Users/fkammer/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.4....
ruby-2.2.4 - #configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.2.4 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.4 - #compiling..............................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/fkammer/.rvm/log/1456431932_ruby-2.2.4/make.log
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:19:35: note: expanded from macro 'numberof'
#define numberof(ary) (int)(sizeof(ary)/sizeof((ary)[0]))
                                  ^~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:2217:21: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'const struct (anonymous struct at ossl_ssl.c:115:14) []'
    for (i = 0; i < numberof(ossl_ssl_method_tab); i++) {
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ossl_ssl.c:19:35: note: expanded from macro 'numberof'
#define numberof(ary) (int)(sizeof(ary)/sizeof((ary)[0]))
                                  ^~~~~
9 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Retrying does not change anything. I also tried to completely uninstall rvm (`rvm implode`) and reinstall it but that was neither successful.

**System**
Mac OS X – El Capitan (10.11.3)
rvm 1.26.11 (latest)
Homebrew 0.9.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with openssl.

rvm uses homebrew as its package manager on my installation (it's the default I guess). You can ensure that with `rvm autolibs homebrew`.

I reinstalled *openssl* with

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

and saw via `brew list` that there was another openssl package called *openssl098* installed on my system. Trying to reinstall it too caused the following error:

```
> brew reinstall openssl098
Error: No available formula with the name "openssl098"
```

I just removed the package with

```
brew uninstall --force openssl098
```

and reinstalled *openssl* again to be sure *openssl098* wasn't a needed dependency. But it wasn't installed again.

Afterwards I tried installing ruby-2.2.4 via rvm again and it worked like a charm :) So I guess my openssl package was broken for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

What helped me:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@3
brew reinstall openssl@1.1
rvm install 3.0.0
```

Comment: Documentation and other SO questions/answers mention openssl 3 is required for some reason. Installing 1.1 worked

Comment: i was facing the similar error  '__rvm_make -j8' and i was able to install the ruby version using openssl@2.8.3 on my mac OS Monterey ( Intel )

Answer (score 1):

`openssl098` has been [officially removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/commit/4e169f22cc48e61e2ed6e2f80a5414fe281db335) and is no longer available. Most probably you have outdated version of `rvm` which tries to build against the `0.9.8` branch. Update `rvm` to have it fixed: `rvm get head`. [Source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues/1150).

Comment: Just reinstalling `rvm` didn't worked for me unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install ruby 1.9.3 but have error as-
Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

I follow @mpapis and got my issue resolved

```
rvm remove 1.9.3
CC=clang rvm install 1.9.3
```

Now I have this setup-

```
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Here is the source link- 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/
& this s my quote on it- 
https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2333

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I always forget to do this. One time thing.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew --prefix openssl # get the path you need for openssl

rvm install "ruby-2.6.4" --with-openssl-dir=PATH_TO_OPENSSL
```